# D3 time parse returns null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As per the instructions on this page: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting I am trying to parse an ISO 8601 date for use in D3.js. My test is almost word for word out of the post, I can't get it to work for a full date time string:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
alert(format.parse("2011-07-01T19:15:28Z"));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add all the fields you're supplying to the format string.

> Unlike "natural language" date parsers (including JavaScript's built-in parse), this method is strict: if the specified string does not exactly match the associated format specifier, this method returns null. For example, if the associated format is the full ISO 8601 string "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", then the string "2011-07-01T19:15:28Z" will be parsed correctly, but "2011-07-01T19:15:28", "2011-07-01 19:15:28" and "2011-07-01" will return null, despite being valid 8601 dates.

Try this:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
alert(format.parse("2011-07-01T19:15:28Z"));
```

That creates a new Date object at the time and date specified.

[image: D3 Time Format]

Comment: Thanks. I thought the format() was an output format and not for the input. I guess I will re-format again to get it into a shortdate.

Answer (score 3):

It is super strict, always check your case. eg:

`format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");` returns **null**

but:

`format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");` gives **valid results**.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was caused by me doing the following:

```
const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
const pos = parseTime(2021-11-13);
// pos is null but does not error!!
```

My mistake was giving an equation of integers subtracting from each other as the input which would result in the line ending up as `parseTime(1997)`. I needed to make it a string like so:

```
const pos = parseTime('2021-11-13');
```

Then `pos` is defined properly.