# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, runtime-error

I am trying to make a line chart in d3, with time on x-axis.  I am using json data in variable. I used d3.time.format() function to format the time, but it gives me above error. I am learning d3 so please help. my code is :

```
<div id="viz"></div>
<script>

var width = 640;
var height = 480;
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
var data = [
{ "at": "2014-11-18T07:29:03.859Z", "value": 0.553292},
{ "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:53.859Z", "value": 0.563292},
{ "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:43.859Z", "value": 0.573292},
{  "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:33.859Z", "value": 0.583292},
{ "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:13.859Z", "value": 0.553292},
{ "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:03.859Z", "value": 0.563292}]; 

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d, i) { return x(d.x_axis); })
.y(function(d, i) { return y(d.y_axis); })
.interpolate("linear");
var vis = d3.select("#viz")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g").attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.xAxis = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse(d.xAxis);
d.yAxis = +d.value;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x_axis; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y_axis; }));

vis.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);
vis.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
vis.append("svg:path")
.datum(data)
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", line);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code so I have created a new one below with some comments on the changes.

```
<style>
   /* You need some styling for your line */
    .line{
        stroke:steelblue;
        fill:none
    }
</style>
<script>

    var width = 640;
    var height = 480;
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
     // You had a mistake filling the domain structure of your scale.
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
    var data = [
    { "at": "2014-11-18T07:29:03.859Z", "value": 0.553292},
    { "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:53.859Z", "value": 0.563292},
    { "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:43.859Z", "value": 0.573292},
    {  "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:33.859Z", "value": 0.583292},
    { "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:13.859Z", "value": 0.553292},
    { "at": "2014-11-18T07:28:03.859Z", "value": 0.563292}]; 
    //You were using non existing variables
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.xAxis); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.yAxis); })
        .interpolate("linear");

    var vis = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g").attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    //You are using ISO format, use the correct time parser
    var iso = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.xAxis = iso.parse(d.at); //You were parsing a non existing variable
        d.yAxis = parseFloat(d.value); //You were parsing a non existing variable
    });
    console.log(data);

     //The variables for the domain were not correct
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.xAxis; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.yAxis; }));

    vis.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);
    vis.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis);

    vis.append("svg:path").datum(data).attr("class", "line").attr("d", line);
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful. Actually i am trying to make a line chart in which input data is the stream from a server. The format and values of data is same as the i have used in the var data. The data from stream gets continuously updated every 10 secs. I want to display data of last 10 mints and wants to update my chart every 10 secs.  I want final output like in link: http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2657838.    Please provide me pointers to make chart in d3. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Infact i tried the same code replacing the value of variable data with the data stream form the server and run the code on local host. Somehow on local host the command "data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.xAxis = iso.parse(d.at); 
        d.yAxis = parseFloat(d.value); 
    });" " is giving error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". please help.

Comment: Hi. ok, so you should create another question for what you are asking because it is very different from your current question, and frankly very complicated. But first, I would study very carefully your example and do multiple trial-and-errors.

Comment: Ok I will post a another question. but for my knowledge please tell me how i can run a d3 chart on loclhost:3000. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. I haven't really used a different port :(. Can you ask another question for this so we can both find out? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle which shows what I think you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/n9s542w0/1/

There were a couple of changes to make.

Firstly, there's some inconsistency about how you use `d.y_axis` vs `d.yAxis` (same with x) to set \ refer to the new elements you add to the data set which you want to plot. I've set these keys to `d.y_axis` and `d.x_axis`.

Next:

```
d.xAxis = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse(d.xAxis);
```

Your `format` here should refer to the input format, rather than the output, and you should be parsing `d.at` rather than `d.xAxis` (see [this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578344/3442309)), so you should have:

```
d.x_axis = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse(d.at);
```

Thirdly, when you append the line you should handle the `data` differently. Change:

```
vis.append("svg:path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", line);
```

to

```
vis.append("svg:path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", line(data));
```

As per [this similar](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5) example

And finally, you were setting the y domain twice but never setting the range. The line:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([height, 0]);
```

should read

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```